# Can I claim more than one Golden Loot Box?

Tags: overwatch

This month's [Twitch Prime reward](https://blog.twitch.tv/overwatch-fans-get-on-the-point-and-get-a-legendary-item-with-twitch-prime-c342b2d49877) is a redeemable code for a Golden Lootbox in Overwatch. Each Twitch prime member is given a single redeemable code for their Battle.Net account.

[image: Promo art for Gold Loot Box]

I've already redeemed the code that came with my Twitch Prime account. However, I have a friend who doesn't play Overwatch who asked me if I wanted his Golden Loot box code.

**Can multiple Golden Loot box codes be used on a single Battle.Net account?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the link](https://blog.twitch.tv/overwatch-fans-get-on-the-point-and-get-a-legendary-item-with-twitch-prime-c342b2d49877) you have in your question:

> *Each Blizzard account may only redeem one code per promotional item.*

It sounds like you can only use one code per account.

Comment: I also would like to say if your friend doesn't plan on using theirs, why not try it yourself?

Comment: My friend ended up giving the code to someone else, so I wasn't able to test.

Comment: Can confirm this, got a code from my gf's prime account and it doesn't work a second time.